# htaccess redirectmatch with conditions and need to query the database

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, redirect, conditional-statements

On our website the users can upload pictures.
For every picture we create a row in the database with 2 fields: the id and a 32 character unique code.
We had like 200.000 pictures in the db and every picture was saved in a certain folder, for example www.site.com/img
At the beginning we use to save picutes in this folder naming the pictures with the 32 unique character code.
For example:
www.site.com/img/afjf4lfn4nafjf4lfn4nafjf4lfn4nas.jpg

After the first 100.000 we start saving the picutes in the folder naming it with the id:
For example:
www.site.com/img/123001.jpg

Now we decided to move all the pictures to Amazon S3.
So we copied all the pictures to S3 naming all the pictues with the id.
So all the pictures on S3 now are named with the id.
For example:
http://d2324324ctqt.cloudfront.net/thumb/95911.jpg

Now we need in the htaccess to redirect all the pictures in the old folder to S3.

like this:
Redirectmatch 301 /img/(.*) http://d2324324ctqt.cloudfront.net/thumb/$1

This is working just for the pictures that was named with the id.

So how I can redirect the first 100.000 pictues that was named with the 32 character code?
In order to do that I need to do query the database to retrieve the id corresponding of the 32 char code.

I think I need something like:
Redirectmatch 301 /img/(.* if is 32 chracter lenght) http://www.site.com/retrieveid.php?code=$1

And in retrieveid.php I will do the query in order to retrieve the id.

Is it possibile something like that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Must you perform the redirect in `htaccess`?  Couldn't you direct all requests to a PHP script (e.g. with ModRewrite) and have that return the relevant 301 header for every case?

Comment: You mean something like:  Redirectmatch 301 /img/(.*) http://www.site.com/retrieveid.php?code=$1   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^img/([a-z0-9]{32})\.jpg$ /retrieveid.php?code=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9]+)\.jpg$ http://d2324324ctqt.cloudfront.net/thumb/$1.jpg [L,R=301]
```

The first rule will account for the 32 character code, and *internally rewrite* the request to `/retrieveid.php`. Then the script can redirect the browser. This saves 1 round trip and the extra redirect.

But if you don't want to use mod_rewrite and want to stick with mod_alias, the order is important:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/img/([a-z0-9]{32})\.jpg$ http://www.site.com/retrieveid.php?code=$1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/img/([0-9]+)\.jpg$ http://d2324324ctqt.cloudfront.net/thumb/$1.jpg
```